# Luainterface 5.1 get all used globals for a script

Tags: c#, luainterface

Is there anyway to get a list of all the names of used globals?

One way is to not load any globals, and then execute the script. let it crash and parse the exception for the name.. very ugly...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `Lua` class has a property called `Globals` witch is `IEnumerable<string>` so you can do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetGlobalsFromFile(string fileName)
{
     using (Lua lua = new Lua())
     {
          lua.DoFile(filename);
          foreach(string global in lua.Globals)
               yeld return global;
     }
}
```

What this method does is it executes a sript and returns all the globas in the file.

Comment: That wont work, it will only return all the registered globals, it does not have anything todo which globals are actually used from the script.. sorry....